# alphamax with macro in spss

Tags: alpha, spss, maximize

I'd like to do a reliabilit analysis and maximize Cronbachs Alpha. I already have the macro for spss, but I don't know where to put the names of the variables for the analysis and what I have to adjust to make the macro fit my variables. The variable names are:

ZQ103_05  &  ZQ103_01 & ZQ408_04 & ZQ305_04 & ZQ405_03 & ZQ406_02 & ZQ201_06 & ZQ301_06 
    & ZQ410_07 & ZQ201_07 & ZQ301_07 & ZQ406_05 & ZQ406_06 & ZQ408_05 & ZQ201_08 & ZQ301_08 & ZQ305_06 
    & ZQ409_05 & ZQ407_07 & ZQ411_02 & ZQ203_09 & ZQ203_04 & ZQ203_06 & ZQ203_07 & ZQ203_09 & ZQ203_10

Here is the macro:

```
    DEFINE alphamax (!POSITIONAL !CHAREND ('/')).
    PRESERVE.
    SET MXLOOPS = 100000000.
    SET LENGTH = NONE.
    matrix.
    get dt/variables = !1/names = nm/missing = omit.
    compute total = rsum(dt).
    compute it = ncol(dt).
    compute n = nrow(dt).
    compute dt = {dt,total}.
    compute ones = make(n,1,1).
    compute dtc = dt-(ones*(csum(dt)&/n)).
    compute vcov = (1/(n-1))*(t(dtc)*dtc).
    compute ivar = diag(vcov).
    compute dt = dt(:,1:it).
    compute x = make(1,it,0).
    compute k = 0.
    compute y = make(((2&**it)-1)-it,it+3,0).
    loop j = 1 to ((2&**it)-1).
    compute x(1,1)=x(1,1)+1.
    loop i = 1 to it.
    do if x(1,i) = 2.
    compute x(1,i)=0.
    compute x(1,i+1)=x(1,i+1)+1.
    end if.
    end loop.
    do if rsum(x) > 1.
    compute ttl = dt*t(x).
    compute tmp = {ttl,total}.
    compute tmpc = tmp-(ones*(csum(tmp)&/n)).
    compute vcov = (1/(n-1))*(t(tmpc)*tmpc).
    compute var = diag(vcov).
    compute r = mdiag(1/sqrt(var))*vcov*mdiag(1/sqrt(var)).
    compute r = r(2,1).
    compute alpha=(rsum(x)/(rsum(x)-1))*(1-(x*ivar(1:it,1))/var(1,1))).
    compute k = k + 1.
    compute y(k,:)= {x, alpha, r, rsum(x)}.
    end if.
    end loop.
    compute res = make(it,3,0).
    loop i = 1 to it.
    compute pre = {make(nrow(y),1,1), y(:,i)}.
    compute b = inv(t(pre)*pre)*t(pre)*y(:,(it+1)).
    compute res(i,:)={b(1,1),(b(1,1)+b(2,1)),b(2,1)}.
    end loop.
    compute tp = make(it,1,-999).
    compute tp2 = tp.
    compute tp3 = tp.
    compute tp4 = tp.
    loop i = 1 to (nrow(y)).
    do if (tp(y(i,it+3),1) < y(i,it+1)).
    compute tp(y(i,it+3),1) = y(i,it+1).
    compute tp2(y(i,it+3),1) = y(i,it+2).
    end if.
    do if (tp3(y(i,it+3),1) < y(i,it+2)).
    compute tp3(y(i,it+3),1) = y(i,it+2).
    compute tp4(y(i,it+3),1) = y(i,it+1).
    end if.
    end loop.
    compute tmp = {t({2:it}), tp(2:it,1), tp2(2:it,1)}.

    print/title = "*** Subtest Statistics are in Data Window ***".
    print res/title = "Mean Scale Alpha for All Possible Scales With 
    and Without Item"/clabels = "Without" "With" "Gain"/rnam/format=F8.4.
    print tmp/title = "Maximum alpha (a_sub) as a Function of Number 
    of Items"/clabels = "Items" "a_sub" "r_sub"/format = F8.4.
    print/title = "* r_sub is correlation between scale with maximum 
    alpha and full scale total.".
    compute tmp = {t({2:it}), tp3(2:it,1), tp4(2:it,1)}.
    print tmp/title = "Maximum Subscale-Full Scale Correlation as a 
    Function of Number of Items"/clabels = "Items" "r_sub" 
    "a_sub"/format = F8.4.
    compute nms = {nm, "a_sub", "r_sub", "items"}.
    print n/title = "Number of cases:".
    save y/outfile = */names = nms.
    END MATRIX.
    format !1 items (F2.0).
    format a_sub r_sub (F6.4).
    variable labels a_sub "Cronbach's alpha".
    variable labels r_sub 'Correlation with total from full scale'.
    variable labels items 'Number of Items'.
    sort cases by a_sub (d).
    RESTORE.
    !END DEFINE.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried to add the variables for"names" but it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Where you see `!1` in the macro body is where the macro will plant the variable names automatically in the syntax when you call it.

Apparently all you need to do is call the macro with your varnames following, this way (note, not "&" signs between variables):

```
alphamax yourVar1 yourVar2 yourVar3 etc'.
```

Comment: It didn't work...I wrote the varnames in the first column after define and alphamax. This is what I get:
>Error # 6807 in column 11.  Text: ZQ103_05
>The DEFINE command does not include parameter definitions within parentheses.
>The lack of any parameters must be indicated by a set of parentheses following
>the macro name.
>Execution of this command stops.
>Error # 6846 in column 120.  Text: !POSITIONAL
>A macro expression includes an undefined macro variable or a macro operator
>which is not valid within an expression.

Comment: Just use the syntax I posted (replacing "yourVar1" etc' with your real variable names) - DO NOT add `define`. EXPLANATION: The syntax you posted is the macro definition. once you run it, the macro is loaded into memory. in order to call the macro you use the macro name and give it the variable list, as in my answer above. SUGGESTION: Since you're using macros it might be a good idea to read up about them a little so you don't get disoriented when you run into problems.

Comment: I tried it and there is written "expect END MATRIX command". I wrote MATRIX, then called the macro and then END MATRIX. but I get errors again..

Comment: this sounds specific for the macro you're using - you should consult with the writer or documentation. In any case the macro includes the `end matrix` command, do not add it outside the macro definition.